# How can i create Dynamic method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

i have to Create method which return's numbers, here's my code whatever i try but i want to do common way for my code, in my code i have same logic but number,number1's values are different,
how can i create method ? or in which way i do common way for my code i don't have to write same logic for deferent's number's

COMMON CODE ONLY number,number1's value change 
    #PART 1:

```
number = [First_color objectForKey:[json objectForKey:@"startColor"]];   // Different from PART2 
number1 = [Last_color objectForKey:[json objectForKey:@"endColor"]];     // Different from PART2 

 //Same code For Both Part
 if(number)
    {
         a = [number integerValue];
         if(a == 14) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
         }
         else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number integerValue]]];
    }

    if(number1)
    {
        b = [number1 integerValue];
        if(a == 10) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
        }
        else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number1 integerValue]-1]];
    }
```

# PART 2:

```
     number = [First_color objectForKey:[objSearch.search firstObject]];  //Different from PART1
     number1 = [Last_color objectForKey:[objSearch.search lastObject]];   // Different from PART2 

   // Same code for both Part
    if(number)
    {
         a = [number integerValue];
         if(a == 14) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
         }
         else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number integerValue]]];
    }

    if(number1)
    {
        b = [number1 integerValue];
        if(a == 10) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
        }
        else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number1 integerValue]-1]];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you simply pass your numbers as parameters of that function? so that you can make a common method with numbers as parameters.

```
-(void)someMethodNameWithNumber:(NSNumber*)number number2:(NSNumber*)number1
{
    if(number)
    {
         a = [number integerValue];
         if(a == 14) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
         }
         else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number integerValue]]];
    }

    if(number1)
    {
        b = [number1 integerValue];
        if(a == 10) {
            b = 11; a = 10;
        }
        else
            [Search addObject:[Data objectAtIndex:[number1 integerValue]-1]];
    }
}
```